# Is there any Iron Python plug-in for Monodevelop?

Tags: .net, ironpython, monodevelop, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed Iron Python on my Ubuntu 10.4 and Mono Develop, but there is no interaction between them. Is there any Iron Python plug-in for Monodevelop as in VS? If not, which is the best Iron-Python IDE for Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: There's a PythonBinding located in `/extras/` in the official repository, but I'm unsure of it's current development state (http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/monodevelop/extras/PythonBinding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of one. The is a Python addin for MD, but not an IronPython addin.

It  wouldn't be hard to write an addin for MD - if anyone's interested, ask on the MonoDevelop mailing list and I can give some pointers to get started.